# Using ingestion-time based pseudo-field (_PARTITIONTIME) as partition while clustering

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to cluster our ingestion-time partitioned tables without having to change the ETL scripts we use to update them. All of our tables are partitioned on the pseudo-field _PARTITIONTIME, now when I try cluster a table with DML I get the following error:

> Invalid field name "_PARTITIONTIME". Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, *TABLE*, *FILE* and _ROW_TIMESTAMP

Here's what the DML-script looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_target`
PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
CLUSTER BY a, b, c
AS
SELECT
  *, _PARTITIONTIME
FROM
  `table_source`
```

How should I go about this? Is there a way to keep the same pseudo-field as the  partition field, should I re-work the partition field, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [Known limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#query_statement) that:

> It is not possible to create an ingestion-time partitioned table from the result of a query. Instead, use a CREATE TABLE DDL statement to create the table, and then use an INSERT DML statement to insert data into it.

In your case, you need to use `CREATE TABLE` to create `target_table` with `CLUSTER BY` first, then migrate data over.